# Chartjs background color multiple Dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery, linq, razor, chart.js

I have a script for Chartjs like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataname = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.performancename));
    var dataquo = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.performancequo));
    var datapo = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.performancepo));
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvasx5');

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: dataname,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'QUO',
                fill: true,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.8)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: dataquo
            }
            ,
            {
                label: 'PO',
                fill: true,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.8)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: datapo
            }]
        },
        borderWidth: 1,
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: true,
            }
            ,
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    stacked: false,
                    barPercentage: 0.8,
                    gridLines: {
                        offsetGridLines: true
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    stacked: false,
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        stepSize: 2,
                        min: 0
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

The result is something like:

[image]

The value for each `var` are:

```
dataname: ['Arif','Choirul','Rexy']
dataquo: [2,2,1]
datapo: [0,0,3]
```

They are on `Array` result.

Why the second and third label is appears with different color? Is something wrong with my script? Need help and advice please.

Thank you.

Comment: what are the values of datapo, dataquo and dataname

Comment: @Strella, Just update the question. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.8)', 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.8)', 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.8)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)', 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)', 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'
                ], .... just for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In V2 Chart.js did not support auto rollover for array collors, so if your array is shorter as the data length it will fallback to the default color for the remaining data entries.

You have 3 ways of fixing it:

- Removing the square brackets so its just a normal color (See example below)
- Providing an array full of colors with the same length as your data array
- Update to V3, although there are some major braking changes so if you want to do this please read the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html) so you can change your code correctly

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="canvasx5" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var dataname = ['Arif', 'Choirul', 'Rexy'];
  var dataquo = [2, 2, 1];
  var datapo = [0, 0, 3];
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvasx5');

  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: dataname,
      datasets: [{
          label: 'QUO',
          fill: true,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.8)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: dataquo
        },
        {
          label: 'PO',
          fill: true,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.8)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: datapo
        }
      ]
    },
    borderWidth: 1,
    options: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          stacked: false,
          barPercentage: 0.8,
          gridLines: {
            offsetGridLines: true
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          stacked: false,
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            stepSize: 2,
            min: 0
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```